# Not loading external js on routing after refreshing the page it gets loaded in Angular 6

Tags: angular, typescript, angular6, angular-routing

[Before refreshing the page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kfFTH.png)
[After refreshing the page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y5Zxs.png)
I'm facing this problem since last 3 days and tried so many ways but none of them worked out for me.
 The problem is I'm Loading the external js from angular.json. It is common js for all the plugin which I'm using like sidebar, dashboard chart, menu toggle and etc.. which works properly on first time page load but when I route the page through component to component or module to component then the js doesn't work until I don't refresh the page.
 If I open the scripts in network tab developer tool in chrome, their I can see my js but still its not loading once I refresh the page it works smoothly as I wanted. Please guide me how I can solve the issue.
Sorry for the language, I hope you got my query.
Thank you

```js
ngOnInit() {
 this.loadScript('../assets/js/scripts/pages/dashboard-lite.js');
}
public loadScript(url: string) {
    const body = <HTMLDivElement>document.body;
    const script = document.createElement('script');
    script.innerHTML = '';
    script.src = url;
    script.async = false;
    script.defer = true;
    body.appendChild(script);
  }
```

Tried loading all the js in home component using this code but still it happens same, I have to refresh the whole page. Tried using js in index.html but no success.

Comment: You have to link these scripts in the `app.component.ts` file.try this method in your `app.component.ts`.

Comment: Thanks Farhat for your reply, I have tried everything like adding all the script inside app.component.ts, then adding inside index.html but none of them worked.

Comment: then try to include this file in `angular.json`. for more details visit this [link](https://www.truecodex.com/course/angular-6/how-to-use-external-js-files-and-javascript-code-in-angular). `"src/assets/js/scripts/pages/dashboard-lite.js"`

Comment: If you see this is my current angular.json

"src/assets/vendors/js/ui/screenfull.min.js",<br>
"src/assets/vendors/js/extensions/pace.min.js",<br>
"src/assets/vendors/js/charts/chart.min.js",<br>
"src/assets/js/core/app-menu.js",<br>
"src/assets/js/core/app.js"<br>

and dashboard-lte.js I'm using only in home-component because chart I wanted only on homepage, but still not working

Comment: ok now just add one more file at after `app.js`. `"src/assets/js/scripts/pages/dashboard-lite.js"`. re-run your angular project and check if it works.

Comment: Tried doing this, added dashboard.js and then re-ran the project. I have done all this steps many times but really dont understand why this is happening. Got this error first time in life and not getting resolved even after trying so many things. I think I have to refresh the whole page on every routing call. What do you think should we try doing that? I know it is not best a approach.

Comment: @rahul_tiwari ,Have you found any solution for this? if So then can you please write your solution out as an answer? it can be helpful for other users running into the same or similar issues to see how you solved it

Answer (score 0):

The file is loaded at runtime, therefore the URL should be relative to the app's base URL, not relative to the project structure. That means that the URL should be `assets/js/scripts/pages/dashboard-lite.js` (i.e. remove the leading `...`).

Comment: Thanks for the reply, My problem is in app.js and app-menu.js. I have sidebar and inside sidebar there is sub menu and toggle button to close and hide the sidebar. Now thing is when I login and comes to homepage the sub menu and toggle button doesnt work because of script, once I refresh the home page it show the dropdwon arrow and toggle button also works fine.
Again when I click on any route and come to home page that again disappears and on refresh it comes.

Comment: For the refrence I have added screenshot, if you see the image with the red mark is after refreshing the page. When it loads first there is no chart or no sub menu arrows after refresh it appears. 
It happen everytime whenever I go on another page and come on home it disappears.

Comment: "node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js",
"node_modules/popper.js/dist/umd/popper.min.js",
"node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js",
"src/assets/vendors/js/ui/perfect-scrollbar.jquery.min.js",
"src/assets/vendors/js/ui/unison.min.js",
"src/assets/vendors/js/ui/blockUI.min.js",
"src/assets/vendors/js/ui/jquery.matchHeight-min.js",
"src/assets/vendors/js/ui/screenfull.min.js",
"src/assets/vendors/js/extensions/pace.min.js",
"src/assets/vendors/js/charts/chart.min.js",
"src/assets/js/core/app-menu.js",
"src/assets/js/core/app.js"

Comment: This is my angular.json, it loads all the js. When I go to network tab developer tool of chrome and when I open the scripts. It shows me all the js of my project but still doesnt load on routing it loads only on page refresh.

Comment: Angular is a single page application, therefore the scripts that are included in `index.html` are only included on startup. It makes sense that scripts are not being reloaded when navigating around the app. If you want to rerun your scripts on route change then you need set up a route change listener and call the scripts in that listener. Perhaps [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41244649/3634032) will help you.

Comment: Thank you for the reply once again, so where should I add this script? I mean in app.component.ts or in every individual component.? and should I remove all the script from angular.json and add all the script in component?

Comment: You only need to add the script in one place, not in every individual component. `app.component.ts` should be ok. Yes you can probably remove the scripts from `angular.json` because the `NavigationEnd` event will also fire at startup as part of its initial navigation.

Comment: this.router.events.pipe(
      filter(event => event instanceof NavigationEnd))
      .pipe(map(() => this.activatedRoute))
      .subscribe((event) => {
        $.getScript('node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js');
        $.getScript('node_modules/popper.js/dist/umd/popper.min.js');
        $.getScript('node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js');
        $.getScript('src/assets/vendors/js/ui/perfect-scrollbar.jquery.min.js');
        $.getScript('src/assets/vendors/js/ui/unison.min.js');

Comment: $.fn.jquery.$.getScript('src/assets/vendors/js/ui/jquery.matchHeight-min.js');
        $.getScript('src/assets/vendors/js/ui/screenfull.min.js');
        $.getScript('src/assets/vendors/js/extensions/pace.min.js');
        $.getScript('src/assets/vendors/js/charts/chart.min.js');
        $.getScript('src/assets/js/core/app-menu.js');
        $.getScript('src/assets/js/core/app.js');
        $.getScript('assets/js/scripts/pages/dashboard-lite.js');
      });

Comment: getting this error "Cannot read property 'getScript' of undefined" tried solving but not getting any solution

Answer (score 0):

I know that its late but for others, i believe that if u wrote the code exists in your JS file on TS it will work
**Example** :
if we import the JS file in our component.ts

```js
import 'src/assets/js/animation.js';
```

whats written in JS is a simple function :

```js
var angularWord = ['A', 'N', 'G', 'U', 'L', 'A', 'R'];
textSequenceAngular(0)
function textSequenceAngular(i) {

    if (angularWord.length > i) {
        setTimeout(function() {
            document.getElementById("angularWord").innerHTML += angularWord[i];
            textSequenceAngular(++i);
    }, 1000);

}
```

But it will run just for the first time; after routing to an other component it wont work as u said;

=> to solve this problem it's better to write this function in component.ts :

```js
  angularWord:string[]=["A","N","G","U","L","A","R"];

    constructor() { }
     ngOnInit(){
      this.typingAngularWord(0);
    }

     typingAngularWord(j:number){
      var ng : HTMLElement = document.getElementById('angularWord') as HTMLElement;

      if(this.angularWord.length > j){
        setTimeout(()=>{
          console.log('var ',j +'= '+this.angularWord[j])
          ng.innerHTML += this.angularWord[j] ;
          j++;
        this.typingAngularWord(j);
        }, 1000);
 }
```